# Is there a way to edit previously saved with PESDK photo?

Tags: android, ios, photoeditorsdk

The use case is the following:

for instance I added a text on an `image`. Saved the `image`. And now I want to edit this `text`. I am looking for a solution to open this image with a text in an `editor` with a possibility to make this text editable. In general, I need to do the same not only with the text.

What I thought about the way to implement such behavior is it would be good if there is some list of the operations applied to the particular image. And also a way to make editor apply these operations again and to have editing components active and available for editing

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by utilizing the serialization feature. More information about that is available at https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/ios/v8/concepts/serialization for iOS and https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v5/concepts/serialization for Android.